# How to handle h:inputText validation?

Tags: validation, jsf

I'd like to display an error next to the fields that are wrong. I have that code for my page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/basic.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Firstname"/>
                <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{account.firstName}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="stringAlphaValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="firstName" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Lastname"/>
                <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{account.lastName}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="stringAlphaValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="lastName" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Login"/>
                <h:inputText id="login" value="#{account.login}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="stringAlphaValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="login" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Password"/>
                <h:inputText id="password" value="#{account.password}" required="true">
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="password" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Address"/>
                <h:inputText id="address" value="#{account.address}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="stringAlphaNumericValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="address" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{account.email}" required="true">
                    <f:validator validatorId="emailAddressValidator"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="email" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Register"/>
            <h:messages globalOnly="true"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

If a field is empty and I press the `Register` button, I get that (here all fields are empty):

[image: Error while empty fields]

(sorry the error is in french. I don't know if it comes from my eclipse language or my tomcat server)

I didn't write this ! This is a text that my program writes on it's own somehow... How do I remove this ?

Also, this is a register page, I'd like to add to my DB the user (if the fields are right) and then change of page with the action `login`. How can I call a method to do that before it changes of page ?

If you need to see more code, like the validator classes, I can add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it this way (personnaly) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/basic.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Firstname"/>
                <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{account.firstName}" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty" validatorMessage="String is not valid (only characters a-z A-Z)">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="firstName" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Lastname"/>
                <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{account.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty" validatorMessage="String is not valid (only characters a-z A-Z)">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="lastName" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Login"/>
                <h:inputText id="login" value="#{account.login}" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty" validatorMessage="String is not valid (only characters a-z A-Z 0-9)">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="login" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret id="password1" value="#{account.password1}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter a password">
                </h:inputSecret>
                <h:message for="password1" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>
                <h:inputSecret id="password2" value="#{account.password2}"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>
                <h:outputText value="Address"/>
                <h:inputText id="address" value="#{account.address}" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty" validatorMessage="Wrong address (eg.: 42bis My address)">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+ [a-zA-Z ]+"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="address" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
                <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{account.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="The field is empty" validatorMessage="The email is not valid">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="email" errorStyle="color:red; display:block"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{account.action}"/>
            <h:messages globalOnly="true"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

```
<h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{account.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your Lastname">
```

And the fields you validate, you can add a `validatorMessage="<Message>"`

** UPDATE ***
If you want to use Bean Validation, like described in my comment,go this way:

```
// for example your NamesBean
@Named(value = "namesBean")
@SessionScoped
public class NamesBean {

// attributes

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Size(min=3, max=10, message="Min 3 and max 10 characters")
public String getFirstname() {
 return firstName;
}

}
```

and the xhtml

```
<h:message for="lastName"/>
<h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{account.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your Lastname">
```

Thats it.

Comment: Nice =) That works a lot better, but how does `validatorMessage` works ? I can't see the message i wrote on it. Also, this is working but what do I return in the validators ? Till now I returned things like : `if (!valid) { FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage( FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "Email is not valid."); throw new ValidatorException(message); }`

Comment: Oh, this FacesMessage is also great if you use Primefaces and you can show such a growl or message component. You can use this nice validation mechanism on different layers, for example in your CDI Bean, write @Size(min=3, max=5, message="Min 3 and max 5 characters") and add a <h:message for="firstname"/> and it will display your defined validation message. This is an example for beanvalidation. For E-Mail Address validation i would suggest to write your own Annotation and define the pattern, the e-mail addres has to match. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkfgx.html there its expl

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where to add this line : `@Size(min=3, max=5, message="Min 3 and max 5 characters")`, could you show me an example? Also, how can I make a variable `requiredMessage` ?

Comment: I have "Size cannot be resolved to a type" and no proposition for any import.

Comment: well, Size is out of the package  `javax.validation.constraints`